# UWP: How to get GridView Item number (not selected by any click) under the mouse (pointer)?

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, mouseover

Is there any way to find out witch `Item` number is under the pointer on `GridView`? I like to show short information about the item under the mouse without selecting the item by any click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could handle the `PointerEntered` and `PointerExited` events for the root element in your `ItemTemplate`.

**XAML:**

```
<GridView>
    <x:Int32>1</x:Int32>
    <x:Int32>2</x:Int32>
    <x:Int32>3</x:Int32>
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid PointerEntered="TextBlock_PointerEntered"
                          PointerExited="TextBlock_PointerExited"
                          Background="Transparent">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>

<TextBlock x:Name="tb" />
```

**Code:**

```
private void TextBlock_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Panel root = sender as Panel;
    var dataObject = root.DataContext;
    tb.Text = dataObject.ToString(); //displays the currently pointed number in "tb"
}

private void TextBlock_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tb.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: OMG! So simple but effective. I didn't realize at all that I can use these events like `PointerEntered` ect **inside** `DataTemplate`. And your example u gave cannot be more clear. Thanks!